# The_excerpt() doesn't parse <!--more--> - how to change that?

Tags: posts, functions, loop, content, excerpt

I'm using `the_excerpt();` in blog.php file (post listing page) and it doesn't recognize `<!--more-->` if "Excerpt" field is empty and it grabs the beginning of the content as excerpt.

This issue is described here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/the_excerpt but I don't know why did WordPress disable `<!--more-->` for the excerpt (if excerpt field is empty and content is used as excerpt)?

Can i enable that back?

Comment: What precisely do you mean by "doesn't parse"? You cover how it works but how does it differ from what you expected and/or want to achieve?

Comment: It displays content after `<!--more-->` tag and doesn't stop at it like it should.

Comment: That is not native behavior. Generated excerpt can't be longer than teaser (from start of post to more tag). Something interferes in your case but it's hard to guess what without more details.

Comment: @Rarst I think nothing interferes - it's now very clear to me what happens and this is already resolved (see accepted answer to this question).

Comment: Well, the behavior you are describing is not correct, so _something_ is wrong with it. Just wanted to comment on that.

Comment: @Rarst If you use `the_excerpt()` then if "Excerpt" is empty WordPress will grab the beginning of the content. But it does not parse `<!--more-->`. Should it parse it? Yes, there's one more thing that is puzzling me - my `the_excerpt();` shows as much content as `the_content();` do even if I didn't modify it in functions.php and it should be set to 70 words. I appreciate your comments, so thanks :)

Comment: It should and _does_ take `<!--more-->` in account. This is my point - if it doesn't for you then it is a problem with your specific installation, not WordPress in general. Same with showing too much content.

Comment: Yes, it does take `<!--more-->` into account as long as you're using `the_content();` and not `the_excerpt();` (see Codex - http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/the_excerpt).

Comment: This is going in circles. Automated excerpt can and does consider `<!--more-->` tag natively (see http://www.rarst.net/script/wordpress-excerpt-teaser/ for write up). If it doesn't - it's a bug something is causing. You can drop by chat some time if you are interested in discussing this in detail.

Comment: In this article he wrote exactly what I wrote - `<!--more-->` works only for `the_content();`. He does not mention `<!--more-->` for `the_excerpt();` and it does not work in default TwentyEleven theme (the reason = excerpt is meant to display excerpt on pages such as search results and it's not user manipulated - it will cut post to 55 words and ignore `<!--more-->`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not know why the WordPress powers that be decided to do it the way they did but [they don't consider the part before the `<--more-->` to be the same as the excerpt](http://codex.wordpress.org/Glossary#Excerpt). Whether that makes sense or not is probably an irresolvable matter of perspective. I'd accept it and make do. The distinction actually adds flexibility to your content management so long as you are aware of what is happening. If you want to use the `<--more-->` just do this...

```
if ( !empty( $post->post_excerpt ) ) the_excerpt();
else the_content();
```

The code that parses the `<--more-->` is hard-coded into [`get_the_content`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.4.2/wp-includes/post-template.php#L197) so it isn't just a matter of removing/adding a filter, though certainly you could juggle filters, or create one, to make this work. That is a more complicated solution and is in my opinion not worth it.

Comment: If there is no pre-made excerpt, `the_excerpt()` triggers `get_the_content('')` via `wp_trim_excerpt()`. So your check is redundant, that happens already by default in core.

Comment: @toscho, the output is not the same. If you use `the_excerpt()` and you have a `post_excerpt` things work as expected. If you do not have a `post_excerpt` then `the_excerpt()` will grab post content and will break on the `<!--more-->` **if and only if** the content before the more is short enough. If the content before the `<!--more-->` is too long-- longer than `$excerpt_length`-- then `the_excerpt()` will **truncate the "more" content anyway**. In order to guarantee that the `<!--more-->` is honored you have to use `the_content()`, not `the_excerpt()`. The switch above is not redundant.